# Getting list of objects in an OkResult

Tags: c#, web-services, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to unit test my web services using Moq, and I have the following test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void GetCoursesTest()
{
    var response = _coursesController.GetCourses();
    var contentResult = response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Course>>;
    Assert.AreEqual(contentResult.Content.Count(), _educationCoursesData.Count);
}
```

Here, `GetCourses()` is:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCourses() 
{
    try
    {
        return Ok(_entities.Courses.ToList().Select(course => new CourseDTO
        {
            Id = course.Id,
            CrsName = course.CrsName,
            CrsHour = course.CrsHour,
            CrsDay = course.CrsDay,
            CrsMin = course.CrsMin,
            Teacher = course.Teacher
        }));
    }
    catch
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

So its result is a list of obejcts. However, when I try to grab the list of these objects into `contentResult` via `response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Course>>;`, `contentResult` is just a `null`. How can I read the list of objects from the OkResult into a variable that I can do `Count()` on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `contentResult` is null after

```
var contentResult = response as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Course>>;
```

the cast failed. The reason is you are using .ToList() to early. By using `.Select(...)` you are creating an `IEnumerable` and no `List`. Try this one:

```
return Ok(_entities.Courses.Select(course => new CourseDTO
            {
                Id = course.Id,
                CrsName = course.CrsName,
                CrsHour = course.CrsHour,
                CrsDay = course.CrsDay,
                CrsMin = course.CrsMin,
                Teacher = course.Teacher
            })ToList());
```

Alternatively change the cast to

```
OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Course>>;
```

Comment: In the end I needed `OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Course>>;`, but you're right, the cast failed, so I'll accept this :)

Answer (score 0):

The method under test is not returning `OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<Course>>` as the content was not enumerated. Either change the expected return type (`OkNegotiatedContentResult<IEnumerable<Course>>`) or update the action to enumerate the collect (`.ToList()`) before returning its data.